# Take the first row then the second etc when joinning two table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Context :

This is a simplification. I will use a simple Cart/Product analogy.
Joe puts 3 TunaCan in his cart. 'Table A' has 3 row. Holding information the Product and the Cart.

For now they are random TunaCan. We wont know their serial before he reachs the grocery checkout.

At the time of payement, we need to associate, each row from the Product to one of the serial we scanned 'Table B'.
A serial - cart product is an unique couple, two product can't have the same serial.
If there is less serial than product the remaning product will have a default serial 'DefaultValue'

Table A : CartProduct(string Product, int CartID)

```
TunaCan 1   
TunaCan 1
TunaCan 1
```

Table B : ScannedProduct(string Serial, Product)

```
Foo         TunaCan
Bar         TunaCan
FooBar      TunaCan
```

The expect result could be :

```
TunaCan     1   Foo 
TunaCan     1   Bar
TunaCan     1   FooBar
```

"Could" because there is 7 possible combinaison for a set of 3 elements.

In LinQ I will use the index to access the row in the second collect

```
var result = TableA.Select((x,i)=> new{ x.propertie, TableB[i]})
```

Comment: Are you aware, that a SQL-Server table has **no implicit sort order** ? If you cannot sort this by any unique column (or a combination of columns) the actual sort order is nothing else than random. This might work a hundred times *as expected* but breaks at any point. I'd suggest to use an additional `IDENTITY` column to ensure the sort order *as inserted*. You say: *In LinQ I will use the index to access the row in the second collect*. This is random too, as the rows can appear at any index...

Comment: @Shnugo, The order doesn't matter.  As long as one is match 1 - 1 with a default value it the is not enought serial.

Comment: Assuming there is a secure sort order guaranteed, `ROW_NUMBER()` is your friend. Use two CTEs to create a numbered set and join them by their row numbers. Just see your comment: You can use this with a random sort order too - but I doubt, that this is the best idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you may try to number your `CartProduct` and `ScannedProduct` tables, and then join them on this number:

```
-- Tables
CREATE TABLE #CartProduct (
    Product varchar(100), 
    CartID int
)
INSERT INTO #CartProduct 
    (Product, CartID)
VALUES 
    ('TunaCan', 1),   
    ('TunaCan', 1),
    ('TunaCan', 1)

CREATE TABLE #ScannedProduct(
    Serial varchar(10),
    Product varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO #ScannedProduct 
    (Serial, Product)
VALUES 
    ('Foo', 'TunaCan'),
    ('Bar', 'TunaCan'),
    ('FooBar', 'TunaCan')

-- Statement 
;WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT 
        Product, 
        CartID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Product) Rn
    FROM #CartProduct
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT 
        Product, 
        Serial,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Product) Rn
    FROM #ScannedProduct
)
SELECT
    cte1.Product Product,
    cte1.CartID CartID,
    ISNULL(cte2.Serial, 'Default value') Serial
FROM cte1
LEFT JOIN cte2 ON (cte1.Product = cte2.Product)  AND (cte1.Rn = cte2.Rn)
```

Output:

```
Product CartID  Serial
TunaCan 1       Bar
TunaCan 1       Foo
TunaCan 1       FooBar
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't include the Creation script my self and you had to do it. I see you are still chainning edit. I usualy finilize my review of answer at the ends of the Week.

Comment: @xdtTransform OK, I've corrected some typing errors.

Comment: Here is your green tick. It works. The query is clear. You added an real mcve with creation script. Just take it. Have a nice weekeend

Comment: @xdtTransform Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do cross join:
select  a.stringproduct,a.cartID ,b.product from A a cross join B b

Comment: Cross Join is a cartesian product. If both table has 3 column the number of result will be 3*3 = 9. When the expected result has only 3 row. Am i missing somethign?

Comment: you are right . You need to add group by in the end.select a.stringproduct,a.cartID ,b.product from A a cross join B b group by  a.stringproduct,a.cartID ,b.product